# How to toggle Submit button `disabled` state if the submit is outside the form?

Tags: redux-form

In the redux-form Simple Form example (http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/simple/) we can see how to control the `disabled` state of the button using the props redux-form generates:
`<button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>`

In my case the submit button sits outside my form in a different component and I'm using an approach like in the Remote Submit example (http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/remoteSubmit/)

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { submit } from 'redux-form'

const RemoteSubmitButton = ({ dispatch }) =>
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => dispatch(submit('remoteSubmit'))}>Submit
</button>

export default connect()(RemoteSubmitButton)
```

but I still want to be able to control the `disabled` state of the button. How can this be done in the most optimal way?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem are redux-form Selectors as described here: http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/Selectors.md/

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { submit, isValid, isPristine, isSubmitting } from 'redux-form';

const RemoteSubmitButton = ({ dispatch, valid, pristine, submitting, formName }) =>
<button
    disabled={!valid || pristine || submitting}
    type="button"
    onClick={() => dispatch(submit(formName))}>Submit
</button>

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    valid: isValid(ownProps.formName)(state),
    submitting: isSubmitting(ownProps.formName)(state),
    pristine: isPristine(ownProps.formName)(state),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RemoteSubmitButton)
```

Pass the `formName` prop to this component to tell the name of the form this button is going to submit e.g.
`<RemoteSubmitButton formName={'remoteSubmit'}`